# CMAC-AES (RFC 4493) calculation in Java

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes

I have key and data:

Now how do I calculate CMAC based on these parameters?

Some more info :

MACs are calculated using AES as the underlying block cipher, according to the CMAC standard described in NIST Special Publication 800-38B. but I'm having a hard time finding proper examples of MAC calculation in java.

EDIT
[this](http://artjomb.github.io/cryptojs-extension/) link works perfectly for this. I need Java samples of this.

Comment: There are several AES based MACs in addition to the one defined in 800-36B.  CMAC is not defined as a MAC that takes in an IV, so I'm curious as to what led you to believe the key and data you're working with is for CMAC, rather than CbcMac, GMAC, AES-CCM, etc.  Either way there should be java libraries that exist that could handle any of these cases.

Comment: My bad there was no IV. I've edited my code.

Comment: I have been trying to find a good java example but no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried Bouncy Castle? It has certainly got a CMAC implementation... Otherwise: you convert from hex to binary, then init the CMAC with the key and then perform the calculation, possibly reverting the result back to hex. You don't need examples for that, do you? Otherwise there should be test classes available.

Comment: I've edited question with what iv tried. I'll check Bouncy Castle out

Comment: Your messages are specified in hexadecimals. You are forgetting to decode your messages. Calling `getBytes` won't do that. And CMAC != HMAC. What did you think, only one character difference so they are about the same???

Comment: @Kritner Bouncy Castle actually provides an extended version of CMAC with IV, commenting that it was not an improvement of IV-free version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone Looking for CMAC AES calculation here it is using Bouncy Castle:

```
 public void getCMAC()
            throws Exception {
        byte[] msg = new byte[]{(byte) 0xA3, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x58,
                (byte) 0xC6, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x4F, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xF0,
                (byte) 0xEA, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x9A, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0xE1,
                (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0xBC, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0xD1};

        byte[] keydata = new byte[]{(byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x1B, (byte) 0x9D, (byte) 0x1D, (byte) 0xC1, (byte) 0x54,
                (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0xA2, (byte) 0x5C, (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x1A,
                (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x0E};

        CipherParameters params = new KeyParameter(keydata);
        BlockCipher aes = new AESEngine();
        CMac mac = new CMac(aes);
        mac.init(params);
        mac.update(msg, 0, msg.length);
        byte[] out = new byte[mac.getMacSize()];
        mac.doFinal(out, 0);

        StringBuilder s19 = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : out) {
            s19.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        }
        Log.e("ecrypted Kmac :", s19.toString());
    }
```

Make sure you add lib like this:

```
 implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56'
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is also using BouncyCastle but is using the Java Crypto API, which is more versatile if a different crypto provider should be used:

```java
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("AESCMAC", new BouncyCastleProvider());
mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"));
mac.update(data);
mac.doFinal(moredata);
```

BouncyCastle has to be added [as a dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.70) before.